# Changing data before Create in Sails API call

Tags: node.js, sails.js

in the `TaskController` I'm trying to insert the current user (i.e. the user who created the task) into the newly created task.

Mostly I've been trying different ways to override `create()` but in the override call the original blueprint and let it continue as usual.

I found a bunch of answers but all seem outdated or otherwise not working. I wonder if there's something more updated.

I'm using Sails v1.0.0-37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

in `\tasks\api\controllers\TaskController.js`

```
  create: function (req, res) {
    req.query.createdBy = req.user.id;
    Task.create(req.query)
      .exec(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.serverError(err);
        }
        return res.ok();
      });
  }
```

My issue:

During all my testing and experimenting I created an empty [lifecycle callback](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) of beforeCreate. Since it was empty, I never called `cb()` so the request just got stuck.